# How to fix npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE when deploying MEAN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack, mongodb-atlas

I'm having an issue deploying my backend to Heroku. I'm using the MEAN stack with a Mongo Atlas Database. The app works fine locally. But once I deploy it, it crashes with an `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`. Apparently, Mongo Atlas requires you to whitelist IP addresses. An article I read said it would work fine if I add my connection string to Heroku environment variables. So I've done so and saved it with the name **connectionString**. However, this did not work. Does the connection string need a specific name? I've posted my Heroku log below. Note I've tried deleting my node_modules and package.json and reinstalling them as well as changing my node version to 10.x.

````
2021-03-17T07:22:23.865572+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2cbf3bbb by user example@example.com
2021-03-17T07:22:23.865572+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user example@example.com
2021-03-17T07:22:24.515688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-17T07:22:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-17T07:22:27.638401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-17T07:22:30.298270+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:22:30.298283+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.1.1 start /app
2021-03-17T07:22:30.298284+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-17T07:22:30.298284+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:22:31.387500+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
2021-03-17T07:22:31.387844+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
2021-03-17T07:22:31.931808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-17T07:23:01.761238+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-17T07:23:01.761850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-17T07:23:01.770367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.1.1 start: `node index.js`
2021-03-17T07:23:01.770621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-17T07:23:01.770728+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-17T07:23:01.772482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.1.1 start script.
2021-03-17T07:23:01.772597+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-17T07:23:01.781656+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:23:01.781807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-17T07:23:01.781869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T07_23_01_773Z-debug.log
2021-03-17T07:23:01.841833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-17T07:23:01.965241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-17T07:23:01.973670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-17T07:23:06.945061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-17T07:23:11.079200+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:23:11.079239+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.1.1 start /app
2021-03-17T07:23:11.079239+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-17T07:23:11.079239+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:23:12.636407+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
2021-03-17T07:23:12.639137+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
2021-03-17T07:23:13.442612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-17T07:23:43.404828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-17T07:23:43.405294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-17T07:23:43.419129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.1.1 start: `node index.js`
2021-03-17T07:23:43.419414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-17T07:23:43.419741+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-17T07:23:43.420082+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.1.1 start script.
2021-03-17T07:23:43.420380+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-17T07:23:43.437105+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-17T07:23:43.439175+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-17T07:23:43.439472+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T07_23_43_421Z-debug.log
2021-03-17T07:23:43.562438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-17T07:23:43.638872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. I was using the config module to load the Mongodb Atlas connection string when connecting to my database.
`mongoose.connect(config.get('configurationString'), {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true}).then(() => winston.info("Connected to MongoDB..."))`

I changed `config.get('connectionString')` to `process.env.MONGODB_URL` then I added the MONGODB_URL env variable to heroku using `heroku config:set MONGODB_URL="<YOUR MONGODB ATLAS CONNECTION STRING>"`. Also make sure you have a Procfile and add the line `web:node index.js`